# How to customize PrimeReact Accordion?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, accordion, primereact

I am working on a project where the requirement is whenever an input element is clicked(focused) accordion should open.

I used below code for this

```
const [accordion, setaccordion] = useState<number>();

const handleAccordion = (id : number) => {
  setaccordion(id);
}

<InputText 
          placeholder="Summarize your problem"
          className="w-100 border border-color question-title-input m-2rem mx-0 mt-0 
          text-q-grey px-4 py-3"
          value={questionTitle}
          onChange={(e) => setQuestionTitle(e.target.value)}
          onFocus={(e) => handleAccordion(0)}
          
        />
```

I passed this as a prop to another component,now I want to update the state of accordion ,could anyone please share their expertise how to do it , I some how reached till below
but not sure how to proceed

```
<Accordion
       onTabChange={e => setState({ activeIndex: [e.index] })}
       activeIndex={id}
      className="q-accordion"
      expandIcon="pi pi-chevron-down"
      collapseIcon="pi pi-chevron-up"
    >
```

Note : accordion should open on click on input element as well as manually also.

Comment: Don't you want to set ` activeIndex={id}` to the value of the accordion panel you want open?  I don't see you doing that.

Comment: @Melloware I have done that in the Accordion component.id I am getting from the input element and I am passing like <Accordion activeIndex = {id} >

Comment: I don't see that in your code above i just see {id}

Answer (score 0):

here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-gwen-5we9qk?file=/src/demo/AccordionDemo.js) which solves your problem.